# I cannot use VS Code with Remmina over VNC, because CTRL keys do not work

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, visual-studio-code, remmina

I cannot run VS Code locally and and use Remote SSH developement, because I am using the Tails OS on my local machine.

But it should be straightforward to use VS Code remotely through VNC.
So I am running VS Code in an `Ubuntu` instance in the cloud, and connecting from my local machine using `Remmina`.

However, when connected to the VNC server with Remmina, I find that most of the CTRL key sequences do not work in the VS Code editor making it unusable. For example, CTRL-Z does nothing. It also looks like CTRL-Z is greyed out in the Edit menu.

I tried to use `screenkey` to see if CTRL-Z was being forwarded but I cannot get `screenkey` to function over the VNC connection (cannot find display error).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Tails OS locally? And why exactly won't a normal LiveCD work? I get that Tails is privacy-focused, but I'm not exactly sure why you would want that for VS Code. Please [edit] your question to include what OS you are running, and what OS the device you are connecting to is running.

Comment: @cocomac I updated my question. I use Tails for privacy reasons. I would like to be able to also do development simulatenously, without rebooting into a LiveCD.